# Trying to get property of non-object with Auth::user()->id withTymonDesign JWT

Tags: php, laravel-5, jwt

I have Laravel 5.1 Api, with JWT TymonDesign Authentication and front end in AngularJs.
So I do login, retrieve token that I will send in all my future ajax call.
But I have problem, and the thing most strange is that return error sometimes and not always, with retrieve User from token.
I have follow this post for my function:
https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/125 and so
I have a AppHelper function that retrieve user:

```
public static function getCurrentUserIdFromRequest($request)
    {
        return Auth::User()->id; //$request->user()->id;
    }
```

But this function, sometimes(yes not always, I don't understand why, if it is a problem of memory or other), return error.

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Like it is null

```
Auth::User()
```

I have tried also with `$request` and  `Auth::id()`, but problem is same.

Comment: do you have a loggedin User when you get the error?

Comment: I tried to dump user, but, return error on other part without dump -.-".. but I tried in other pc with different localServer, and the problem there isn't...so maybe the problem is my webserver Xampp..because in other pc it work always and never return  this error... WTF :(

Comment: try this instead Auth::id();